# Clear the notification when app is finished

Tags: android

I know there are many similar questions, but I am unable to find the solution for my problem. I am using IntentService in which I am downloading a file. I am showing the downloading in notification. The problem is if I force close the app, the notification stuck there. Is there any way to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void CancelNotification(Context ctx, int notifyId) {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(ns);
        nMgr.cancel(notifyId);
    }
```

pass notification id when msg receive .

Comment: please call this function in your onterminate() in application.

Comment: As per the documentation onTerminate never gets called on actual android devices and only in emulator environment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this post: [How to determine if the Android Application was force closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700542/how-to-determine-if-the-android-application-was-force-closed)

It's not possible to detect that app was force killed, hence you don't get callback to remove the notification.

If you have some callback to handle when service is done you can use:

```
NotificationManager.cancel(int id)
```

Could be possible to have always running background `Service` polling running applications and that way detect that the process was closed/killed and remove notifications.

Comment: thanks for reply! I was thinking that the notification is made using the context of the activity. So, if I force close the app, wouldn't it get destroyed? What do you think?

Comment: The notification stays even if application was not running or was running and was closed.

Comment: Cannot say 100% sure there is no way, perhaps always running background service could poll running application processes and detect that your application is not running anymore and then cancel all notifications.

Comment: You mean using Service instead of InentService?

Comment: Yes, I think IntentService stops after handling the Intent.